# Angular 2: navbar icon color change based on route

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

**UPDATED ANSWER**

See below for the original question. But thanks to @Smit for leading me to the solution.

Here is the updated Plunker with the solution: [Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/k2epPWvMN1stFAq1rSwF?p=preview)

Now there may be a better way to solve this, but this is how I have for the time being.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
      <div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="red">Red <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="blue">Blue <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"><i [ngClass]="setClasses()" class="icon-emotsmile icons"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Please click on links in navbar.</h1>
    <hr><hr>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  someProperty = true;
  anotherProperty = true;

  setClasses() {
      let classes =  {
          redText: this.someProperty,    
          blueText: this.anotherProperty, 
      };
      return classes;
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) {
        router.events.subscribe(e => {
          if(e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            if(this.router.url === '/' || this.router.url === '/home') {
              this.someProperty=false;
              this.anotherProperty=false;
            console.log("I am home")
          }
          else if(this.router.url === '/red') {
            this.someProperty=true;
            this.anotherProperty=false;
            console.log("I am red")
          }
          else if(this.router.url === '/blue') {
            this.someProperty=false;
            this.anotherProperty=true;
            console.log("I am blue")
          }
          else {
            console.log("wrong")
          }
          }
        });
      }
  ngOnit() {}
}
```

Basically I used Router/NavigationEnd to find the router url and from there I used ngClass to add/remove classes.

**EDITED on 02/21/2017**

I'm trying to change the color of the navbar icons when the user is viewing certain pages.

For example, if the user is viewing the home page, the icons should be grey, but when the user if viewing the red page the icons will be red.

I am using Angular 2 and Bootstrap 4. Here is the basic setup.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
      <div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="red">Red <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="blue">Blue <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"><i class="icon-emotsmile icons"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Please click on links in navbar.</h1>
    <hr><hr>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnit() {}
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RedComponent }   from './red.component';
import { BlueComponent }   from './blue.component';
import { HomeComponent }   from './home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'red', component: RedComponent },
  { path: 'blue', component: BlueComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-home',
  template: `
    <h2>HOME</h2>

    <p>I want the navbar to be <b>grey</b> and the smile icon to be <b>grey</b>.</p>
  `
})
export class HomeComponent {}
```

**red.component.ts** and **blue.component.ts** are basically the same as **home.component.ts**.

I have created a plunker: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/k2epPWvMN1stFAq1rSwF?p=preview)

Comment: You'll have a hard time finding accurate documentation and answers if you still use the completely obsolete alpha.46 version of angular. It's been released in final version for quite a long time now.

Comment: Sorry I used an older version of angular. I am actually using the current version.... let me fix the plunker and edit my post.

Comment: @JBNizet I have edited the plunker.

Comment: You could probably use `@Input and @Output` decorators to the tasks. Or get the url path to identify which path it is currently on and then do the changes.

Comment: @Smit How would I get the url path to then update the change?

Comment: @JessySue See the answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after a bit research i found the following to detect changes to the url path.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        router.events.subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
      }
```

This is subscribe all the changes on the url path.

And in the console you can see the following object.

```
NavigationEnd {id: 1, url: "/newExt", urlAfterRedirects: "/newExt"}
```

upon redirecting to different extension

```
NavigationEnd {id: 2, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/"}
```

This way u can do what u want with ur specific extensions.

PS: I placed the constructor in the app.component where the router-outlet lies.

Comment: thanks! I will play around with this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have updated my original post to show the changes that I made.

Comment: @JessySue Thank you for the mention. If you appreciated the effort to select the answer. And also let me know if you required any more information.